# How to create a shortcut for forward delete on a Mac?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

I'd like to create a shortcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> which performs a forward delete (the same as the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key). I use it (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) on a Mac and I find it very useful.

Is this feasible?

Comment: On GNOME Shell you can [create a shortcut to `xdotool`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190716/349837)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I tried to do it with `xmodmap`, but, apparently, it can't catch <kbd>Fn</kbd>, so I tried it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> options.

You can see the current behavior of `BackSpace` using:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep BackSpace
```

and the output it gives is:

```
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
```

The different values correspond to the different modifiers:

```
1st: no modifier
2nd: shift
3rd: ctrl
4th: ctrl-shift
```

So we would like to change either the 3rd or the 4th value. We can do this by executing:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace Delete BackSpace"
```

or:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace Delete"
```

respectively, but unfortunately this does not work for me. I think these values are overridden on some deeper level and both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> still deletes a word backwards.

So I think you're stuck just using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key...

Answer (score 0):

Very very old question, but just for reference:

1. in later Linux/Ubuntu/Kubuntu: Fn+Backspace works as delete just like on OSX

In case Fn+Backspace is not working or is not convenient (Fn can be  bottom left, backspace top right and two hands are needed) etc:

2. some applications, like in Plasma, have their own editable shortcuts to delete next character (Kate text editor) or to delete files (Dolphin file manager):

[image]

[image]

3. There is also the affordable solution to [Turn Caps Lock key into delete key](https://askubuntu.com/q/1405207/925128) (as uppercase can be triggered pressing Shift)
4. in order to create another shortcut for Delete (like Super+Backspace or Shift+Backspace), see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190735/925128) (but don't use it simultaneously with settings like at point 2 above!); also, this doesn't seem to work as expected: see this: [Remapped Shift+Backspace to Delete works only for some applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416040/remapped-shiftbackspace-to-delete-works-only-for-some-applications), so maybe point 3 is preferable