# Is it possible to create a shortcut for forward delete?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Before I get downvoted and castigated - yes - this question has been asked (link below) but was not answered.

So, like the title suggests, does anyone know how to create a forward delete button using special keys on Ubuntu?

Thanks

previous link: [How to create a shortcut for forward delete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158333/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-forward-delete)

Comment: The question was answered and the answer accepted.