# How to create a keyboard shortcut to emulate a specific keystroke (not a command)?

Tags: keyboard, mac

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 on a Mac, and so I do not have a <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on my keyboard.

To emulate that key, I can do <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> but I would like to choose another combination of keys like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

This will do the job:

**Firstly:** edit the XKB `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

**Secondly:** find this line:

```
key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };
```

And comment it out by adding `//` before it like so:

```
//key <BKSP> {  [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };
```

**Thirdly:** copy and paste the following code below the commented line in **secondly** above:

```
key <BKSP> {
    type= "PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]=  [ BackSpace, Delete ]
};
```

And save the file.

**Fourthly:** clear the XKB cache by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

**Finally:** reboot your system to activate your new xkb configuration or reload the new xkb configuration by setting an xkb map layout using the following command in the terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

and test your new key combination.

---

This solution should make pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> +
<kbd>Backspace</kbd> work as pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

To change the combination to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
you can change `PC_SUPER_LEVEL2` to `PC_SHIFT_LEVEL2` in **thirdly**
above.

Comment: Super.. Nice Explanation.. is it possible to make multiple Deletes by pressing `Super+BackSpace`. I mean if I want to delete 100 characters.. do I need to Hold Super and then press n release Backspace for 100 times..

Comment: I think that `sudo gedit` isn't encouraged. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/802649/248158) for example.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, it is possible. You do not need to press and release Backspace for 100 times. The combination keys should behave exactly like the Delete key on a PC keyboard.

Comment: I am not sure about this.. Have you checked it?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica You think right. Thank you for your useful comment.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, just to make sure I have now tested it on a PC not a Mac and it works as described in my comment. Thank you

Comment: oh, nice.. thanks for conformation Raffa!!! well done..

Comment: @JusticeforMonica wrong link

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [Remapped Shift+Backspace to Delete works only for some applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416040/remapped-shiftbackspace-to-delete-works-only-for-some-applications)

Answer (score 1):

A command could emulate a specific keystroke. One way to do this is to create a custom shortcut to run [`xdotool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html) ([source](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)) on *Settings > Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts*:

[image: screenshot]

- Possible duplicate/related: [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/872695/349837) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/158333/349837).
- [Another way](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/2kz9hj/how_to_use_the_del_key/clq5fcy/)

Comment: Why do you have `&& sleep 1`?

Comment: I updated the answer, doesn't seem to be needed (as it was [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/872698/349837), with [CLEARMODIFIERS](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html#clearmodifiers))

Comment: xdotool involves a command, which is dismissed in the question. if xdotool is acceptable, even separate keys (not just two-key shortcuts) can be used for delete, something which seems more logical on a keyboard without a delete key. [Capslock](https://askubuntu.com/q/1405207/925128) seems the best candidate, as shift can be used for uppercase

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be possible to do it overall, <kbd>Fn</kbd> can't be seen as another key, according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19565/829702) :

> The <kbd>Fn</kbd> is not really comparable. It's a hardware key that's not directly interfaceable by the operating systems. Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> and another key causes an entirely different code to be sent to the operating system. 
>   Examples for this include XF86AudioMute, XF86Eject and so on. The Operating system can't detect whether <kbd>Fn</kbd> is pressed or not.

I had think that it would be possible using `gnome-tweaks`package, inside :

*Keyboard & mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options*

but no, you can define behavior for each special key (from the basical <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the old <kbd>Meta</kbd> key), but because <kbd>Fn</kbd> isn't a software key, you can't change his function.

You can create a custom shortcut to do that <kbd>Delete</kbd> emulation, but it required a command.

Comment: You can always use `xev` to see if the X11 server receives a keypress and which when the key is pressed.  If nothing happens when pressing and releasing for instance the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button, then you cannot handle it inside X11 (for Linux this means in software)